# Get next class with specified class name by div ID anywhere on the page using Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

I'm tying to get next div element with soecified class name `.select_track` by Div Id.

The items every where on the page has same class name `.select_track`
Some tracks maybe repeated on other sections and by the reasons I have different DIV IDs for different sections. In the first section items have id `track_'.$row->id.'` and in the second section items has id `geotrack_'.$row->id.'`

**This is my code to select, get index, play the track:**

```
// This variable keeps the item index
let keepIndex = null;

// .hoveredPlayTriger class is child of .select_track
$(document).on('click', '.hoveredPlayTriger', function(e) {
    // some codes here

    // That way I'm getting the current class index 
    keepIndex = $(this).closest('.select_track').index();

    // And just logging here to see what it returns
    console.log('Current index:'+keepIndex);
    
   // some other codes here
});
```

**And the thing is happens here**

```
"#fplayer_next" is player next track button
$(document).on('click', '#fplayer_next', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    
    // The following variable has value: div#track_{{ $row->id }} or div#geotrack_{{ $row->id }}
    let preferToCatch = 'div'+keepSelector;

    // Here we are incracing the keeped index number + 1
    let nextIndex = keepIndex + 1;
    
    // That way we shoud get the next element
    let nextId = $('.select_track').eq(nextIndex).attr('id');

    // Here we are checkng what a hell it gonna return
    console.log('next index:'+nextIndex+'    and ID: '+nextId);
    
    // And that's it. We are clicking to next element to play the next song
    $('#'+nextId+' .hoveredPlayTriger').click();
});
```

My current code works properly for the first sections and it goes properly to next section's first element too.

We can play **next** song **till** the **second element** of the **second sectio**n.
We can move to next **from last element of the first section** to **first elemnt of the second section** but than it return **index:0** and starts selecting the **second element of the first section** instead of the **second elemnt of the second section**.

It's a little bit hard to explain what I'm doing.
Let's see the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1u_kwzTA3fQ

I need some solutions

Answer (score 0):

Today I wrote that one and it works almost properly but it still have some issues

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.active').click();
});

let keepTheID = null;
let keepIndex = null;
$(document).on('click', '.select_item', function(e) {
    if (keepTheID !== $(this).attr('id')) {
        $('.active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        keepTheID = $(this).attr('id');
        keepIndex = $(this).index();
    }
});

$(document).on('click', '.next', function(e) {
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $('#' + keepTheID).click();
    keepIndex = keepIndex + 1;
    let next = $('.select_item').eq(keepIndex).first().addClass('active');
    console.log(next);
});

$(document).on('click', '.prev', function(e) {
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $('#' + keepTheID).click();
    keepIndex = keepIndex - 1;
    let next = $('.select_item').eq(keepIndex).first().addClass('active');
    console.log(next);
});
```

```css
html, body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
body {
    padding-bottom: 40px;
}
* {
    font-family: arial;
}
pre {
    font-family: monospace;
}
a {
    color: rgb(24, 111, 7);
}
h2.main {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #333;
    color: #eee;
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    font-size: 34px;
    font-weight: normal;
}
div.main {
    font-size: 20px;
    background-color: #eee;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 6px 0;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    font-weight: normal;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #aaa;
}
div.main .content {
    text-align: left;
}
div.main.contd {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
hr {
    border: 0;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #aaa;
    margin: 10px 0;
}
.content {
    margin: auto;
    width: 980px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
div.desc {
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 1.6;
    color: #222;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    font-size: 15px;
}
div.desc strong {
    color: #000;
}
#buttons {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
#buttons > * {
    float: left;
}
#buttons span {
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #333;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 5px 0;
}
#buttons a {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 6px;
    padding: 5px 8px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #eee;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 1px solid #555;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #222;
    color: #333;
}
#buttons a:hover {
    background-color: #555;
    color: #fff;
}
.leftpane .button {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #eee;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: normal;
    border: 1px solid #555;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #222;
    color: #333;
    width: 120px;
    padding: 6px 10px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 320px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.leftpane {
    float: left;
    width: 395px;
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: rgb(214, 241, 145);
    border-radius: 8px;
}
.rightpane {
    float: left;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-left: 15px;
}
.clear {
    float: none;
    clear: both;
}
pre.prettyprint {
    width: 520px;
    padding: 15px;
    padding-right: 0;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 1.7;
}
pre.prettyprint span {
    font-family: monospace, courier new, courier;
}
pre.prettyprint.full {
    width: auto;
    padding: 6px 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    line-height: 1.3;
    font-size: 12px;
}
ol.desc {
    list-style-type: decimal;
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    list-style-position: inside;
}
ol.desc li {
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
ol.desc li:first-child {
    margin-top: 0;
}
.active {
    background-color: #0aa !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <!--start first section-->
  <section class="first_section">
    <div class="sectionTitle">First section</div>
    <div class="grid">
      <div class="select_item" id="first_section_1">1</div>
      <div class="select_item" id="first_section_2">2</div>
      <div class="select_item active" id="first_section_3">3</div>
      <div class="select_item" id="first_section_4">4</div>
      <div class="select_item" id="first_section_5">5</div>
      <div class="select_item" id="first_section_6">6</div>
      <div class="select_item" id="first_section_7">7</div>
      <div class="select_item" id="first_section_8">8</div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <!--start second section-->
  <section class="second_section">
    <div class="sectionTitle">Second section</div>
    <div class="grid">
      <div class="select_item" id="second_section_1">1</div>
      <div class="select_item" id="second_section_2">2</div>
      <div class="select_item" id="second_section_3">3</div>
      <div class="select_item" id="second_section_4">4</div>
      <div class="select_item" id="second_section_5">5</div>
      <div class="select_item" id="second_section_6">6</div>
      <div class="select_item" id="second_section_7">7</div>
      <div class="select_item" id="second_section_8">8</div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
<div class="controls">
  <div class="prev">
    <i class="las la-angle-left"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="next">
    <i class="las la-angle-right"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Seems CSS doen't work on stackoverflow.

Source on codepen:
https://codepen.io/webtm/pen/mdxMwrL?editors=1010

The issue:
https://youtu.be/L4jUW5ZvcHE

Answer (score 0):

So, I solved the issues myself.

My code looks like this now:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.active').click();
});

let keepTheID = null;
$(document).on('click', 'body .select_item', function(e) {
    if (keepTheID !== $(this).attr('id')) {
        $('.active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        keepTheID = $(this).attr('id');
    }
});

let getNextSection = (section_id) => {
    let sections = $('.content_section');
    if (sections.length) {
        let outId = null;
        for (let index = 0; index < sections.length; index++) {
            const element_id = sections.eq(index).attr('id');
            let plusindex = index + 1;
            if (element_id == section_id && plusindex <= sections.length) {
                return sections.eq(plusindex).attr('id');
            }
        }
    }
};

let getLastSection = (section_id) => {
    let sections = $('.content_section');
    if (sections.length) {
        let outId = null;
        for (let index = 0; index < sections.length; index++) {
            const element_id = sections.eq(index).attr('id');
            let plusindex = index - 1;
            if (element_id == section_id && plusindex >= sections.length) {
                return sections.eq(plusindex).attr('id');
            }
        }
    }
};

let current_item = null;

$(document).on('click', '.next', function(e) {
    // Keep current .active => #ID
    current_item = '#' + $('.active').attr('id');

    let next = $('.active').next();
    let lastNextId = null;

    if (typeof next.attr('id') === "undefined") {
        let current_section = $(current_item).closest('.content_section').attr('id');
        // console.log(current_section, 'ამ სექციაში მეტი ელემენტი აღარაა და შემდეგი სექცია მოვძებნოთ');

        let run = getNextSection(current_section);

        if (typeof run !== "undefined") {
            $('#' + run + ' .select_item:first').click();
            console.log(run);
            return false;
        }

        $('.content_section:first .select_item:first').click();
        return false;
    }

    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    next.addClass('active');
});

$(document).on('click', '.prev', function(e) {
    // Keep current .active => #ID
    current_item = '#' + $('.active').attr('id');

    let prev = $('.active').prev();
    let lastLastId = null;

    if (typeof prev.attr('id') === "undefined") {
        let current_section = $(current_item).closest('.content_section').attr('id');
        // console.log(current_section, 'ამ სექციაში მეტი ელემენტი აღარაა და შემდეგი სექცია მოვძებნოთ');

        let run = getLastSection(current_section);

        if (typeof run !== "undefined") {
            $('#' + run + ' .select_item:last').click();
            console.log(run);
            return false;
        }

        $('.content_section:first .select_item:last').click();
        return false;
    }

    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    prev.addClass('active');
});
```

Here are the code links. The resources may help someone in future.

Easier one: https://codepen.io/webtm/pen/mdxMwrL

Hard one: https://codepen.io/webtm/pen/ExEvbEW